# Nested JSON parse in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nested-loops

**How to change this to swift struct form, if i want all datas from all loops?**

Means
from `commonsOfList` I want `storid`,`id`,`isActive`,`keyname`,`status`,`value` like all data I want from all loops

```
    Optional({ 
    storeName = DocStore;
    commonsOfList =     (
                {
            storeId = 0;
            id = 1;
            isActive = 0;
            keyname = Contacts;
            status = 0;
            value = store;
        },
                {
            storeId = 0;
            id = 2;
            .
        .
    .   },
    .
    .   
    .

    );
 currentDate = "2018/11/05";
    grandTotals =     (
                {
            storeId = 0;
            commonId = 0;
            consentId = 0;
            Id = 0;
            grandTotal = 300;
             },
                {
            storeId = 0;
            commonId = 0;
            consentId = 0;
            Id = 0;
            grandTotal = 5500;
            }
    .   
    .
    {
    .   
    .
 }
    );
staffList=     (
                {
            accountExist = 0;
            adharId = 123456789012;
            admnId = 0;
            advanceAmount = 0;
            age = 18;
            storeId = 0;
    mob.No = 9876543200
        }
    .
    .
        {

    .
});
 procedureCommonId =     (
                {
            storeId = 0;
            commonId = 1;
            consentId = 0;
            Id = 0;
            paymentid = 0;
            InvoiceStatus = 0;
            proPlannDate = "25/10/2018";
            Status = 0;
            taxId = 0;
            totalCost = 0;
            totalDisCost = 0;
            PlanId = 0;
        },
             {
    .
    .
});
 storeList = (
   {
    :
    :
    :
   });
```

**

```
   struct list: Decodable {

  let name: String
  .
  .
  .

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case name = "name"
     .
     .
     .

}
}
```

**

if you know this please respond
thank you

Because the mapping between JSON keys and container properties and the parsing syntax are tightly coupled, we are going to examine the details for both, at the same time.

Comment: You should use swiftyjson https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: please explain with this json example?

Comment: @IOSSingh No they should not, this library is obsolete now that Swift has the Encodable/Decodable protocol.

Comment: @IOSSingh You should not suggest `SwiftyJSON` when you have Codables.

Comment: @SruthiCS if you can provide a readable JSON response then it will be easy to provide a better fix.

Comment: What are all those dots `.` Do edit your question

Comment: .  means same repeating